# Retrofit post using Firebase

Tags: java, android, firebase, retrofit2

Please any one please help. This is My API method

```
@POST("/user/new.json")
Call createUser(@Body User user);
```

This is my call in `MainActivity`

```
 Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl("https://XXXXXX.firebaseio.com").addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

    Api api=retrofit.create(Api.class);

    User user=new User(1,"Sam");

    Call<User> call=api.createUser(user);
    call.enqueue(new Callback<User>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(Call<User> call, Response<User> response) {
            Log.d("sam","run");
        }

        @Override
        public void onFailure(Call<User> call, Throwable t) {
            Log.d("sam","error");
        }
    });
```

This is `User.java`

```
public class User {

        int id;

        String name;

        public User(int id, String name) {
            this.id = id;
            this.name = name;
        }
    }
```

Output is coming like that :-

```
"user" : {"new" : {"-KBgcQTomo8xGpnv5raM" : {"id" : 1,"name" : "Sam"}}}
```

But i want output like that :-

```
"user" : {"new" : {"id" : 1,"name" : "Sam"}}
```

Here is Tutorial For [Retrofit + Firebase](http://sushildlh-retro-firebase.blogspot.in/)

please help................

Comment: Please modify your API. Whatever API sends you receive. Also, none of the JSON looks valid. Missing `}`

Comment: @Rohit can u help me how i change .....

Comment: public interface Api {
        @POST("/user/new.json")
        Call<User> createUser(@Body User user);
    }

Comment: in the end }} i forgot..

Comment: Do you mean this JSON is your post data? I thought this is what your API is returning.

Comment: "user" : {"new" : {"-KBgcQTomo8xGpnv5raM" : {"id" : 1,"name" : "Sam"}

Comment: post data return this

Comment: but i am not sending this -KBgcQTomo8xGpnv5raM name

Comment: This is the JSON you are sending or you are getting back in `onResponse`?

Comment: i am sending only this JSON through post method  {"id" : 1,"name" : "Sam"}

Comment: You want to send this but a different json is being sent, right? If yes, please post `User.java`

Comment: can u please explain in brief . i didn't get your point .

Comment: Since you are using firebase, it is better to use their Android library rather than using Retrofit. Check more here: https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/

Comment: firebase response time is slow as compare to retrofit.

Comment: Is there necessity to user *Firebase* with *Retrofit*, as we know Firebase doing all the operation in background itself. I have posted my answer. May it will helps you.

Comment: If you really want the user under "new" then I think you just have to change POST to PUT. .  I gave an answer of how I would normally do it, since I don't get why you want to only support one "new" user?

Answer (score 11):

In firebase, when you [POST](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-post) you are attempting to push to a [list of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/guide/saving-data.html#section-post) stored under the POST's URL. Consequently, it is impossible to POST to /user/new.json and not store the data under a new firebase generated key like "-KBgcQTomo8xGpnv5raM" beneath /user/new.

If you want complete control of where you are putting the data you must use [PUT](https://www.firebase.com/docs/rest/api/#section-put). However, putting your new entry directly as /user/new would not make sense. Where will subsequent entries go?

If you are not accepting server side keys assignment, then the normal solution would be to use some part of the entry that you will enforce uniqueness on. For example, either the name or numeric id could be the key for the new user so that multiple users may be added.

Based on the retrofit API and using name as the unique key, this:

```
@POST("/user/new.json")
Call createUser(@Body User user);
```

would become:

```
@PUT("/user/new/{name}.json")
Call createUser(@Path("name") String name, @Body User user);
```

and:

```
Call<User> call=api.createUser(user);
```

would then be:

```
Call<User> call=api.createUser(user.name, user);
```

now the layout would be:

```
"user" : {"new" : {"Sam": {"id" : 1,"name" : "Sam"}}}
```

so future users could be added as long as they were not named Sam.

Comment: How you get this name in the `@Path("name") String name` is `-KBgcQTomo8xGpnv5raM` .It is very difficult to identify that  anonymously named . I have done with PUT,DELETE,GET but i have only problem with POST .

Comment: @sushildlh , If you use POST, whatever you create will get a new leaf in the path with this kind of randomness. If you use PUT, you control the entire path in the url you put to, but then you need to use path manipulation in retrofit if you want to support more than one of something.

Comment: @sushildlh , If you are looking to avoid random key ids then you are trying to PUT.  The whole point of post is that it generates these so you can post to a parent and get a new non-conflicting child as many times as you like. You can make your own paths/keys exactly as you want them with put, or accept random ids with post..

Answer (score 9):

## **I don't think you have to use `Retrofit` to post data.**

There is [Way to Saving](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html#section-ways-to-save) data in Firebase. May you know that Firebase managing all the thing in background itself.

I don't know why are you posting data using **Retrofit.**

Snippet to send and update automatically.

```
public class User {
    private int birthYear;
    private String fullName;

    public User() {}

    public User(String fullName, int birthYear) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.birthYear = birthYear;
    }

    public long getBirthYear() {
        return birthYear;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }
}

Firebase alanRef = ref.child("users").child("alanisawesome");

User alan = new User("Alan Turing", 1912);

alanRef.setValue(alan);
```

**You can also save data directly to a database location:**

> //Referencing the child node using a .child() on it's parent node
>   alansRef.child("fullName").setValue("Alan Turing");
>   alansRef.child("birthYear").setValue(1912);

It will save as you want:

```
{
  "users": {
    "alanisawesome": {
      "birthYear": "1912",
      "fullName": "Alan Turing"
    }
  }
}
```

Please follow the docs: [Saving Data in Firebase](https://www.firebase.com/docs/android/guide/saving-data.html)

Thank you.

Comment: i using retrofit bcoz response time of retrofit is good compare to firebase....anyway thanx for response

Comment: I don't think dear, How you will use Retrofit with Firebase.

Comment: Welcome and if you can do that any how then please let me know. As I want to learn. Keep it up. Keep #RetroFiring . :)

Comment: **1)** Answer should bring the solution for the case Firebase + Retrofit as OP requested instead of suggesting using the Firebase SDK. **2)** It's good practice to implement REST API that can be changed in the future instead of using proprietary SDK with which you need to stick until complete rewrite...

Answer (score 3):

As @sushildlh said it's not really worth to use retrofit in this case (if we are thinking about request send / respond timers), but it's good android programming practice. And I'm sure that you should still use retrofit.

But it's not the point. Your problem is in your API on the firebase. Create your own json file with a response that you want to get and upload it on the firebase.

Cheers