# What are these in Firebase database? Please see details

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I am saving some data in firebase.

The data is getting saved under something else then `Uid`.

It is getting saved under these:

[image], [image]

What are these called?

While `Uid`s look like this:

[image]

I want to know this because I want to fetch data present under them. When I try to fetch data with this code:

```
        retrieveRefUid.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), dataSnapshot.getValue().toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {
                Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), firebaseError.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });
```

it fetches nothing and gives a blank `Toast`.

P.S: I'm sure that I'm specifying the path correctly.

Please let me know what are these (2 images above) called so that I can fetch the data underneath them.

Sorry for bad formatting of the question. I'm still a beginner here.

Comment: I am not sure but i think this is random generating name by the firebase. Its happen with me also but i didn't get the actual answer . This my question :-http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722617/retrofit-post-method

Comment: @SushilKumar then how to retrieve data from there?

Comment: actually i am also searching how to get data after post data into firebase.

Comment: may be some backhand work there 2 store data into format(without random generating name)....

Comment: @Hammand Is you get the solution ??

Comment: Is you get the answer ???

Comment: No. I haven't got the answer yet, but Frank can answer this question. You have to provide the link to this question by commenting on his answer in the link I provided you.

Comment: i commented on that link may be he busy in something .......

Comment: @Sushilkumar give link to my question also

Comment: don't worry we both have same problem if he answer i will tell you ...............

Comment: @SushilKumar don't ping me on questions. If I have time I will help, pinging me does not make I suddenly give me more time.

Comment: Please include the JSON that exists at `retrieveRefUid`. Be sure to always include JSON as text, which you can easily get by clicking the Export button in your Firebase database. Having the JSON as text makes it searchable, allows us to easily use it to test with your actual data and use it in our answer and in general is just a Good Thing to do.

Comment: These are push id for push you do in database in firebase

Answer (score 0):

> What are these called?

Those keys are called push ids, since they generated by Firebase's `push()` method. They are documented in the [Firebase guide on saving lists of data](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push) and in this [blog post in their implementation](https://www.firebase.com/blog/2015-02-11-firebase-unique-identifiers.html).

Comment: Sorry for Ping and thanx for your time .