# Retrofit gives error Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY

Tags: android, json, retrofit

I just started using Retrofit library today. I am having problems getting some json data.

JSON data I'm trying to get looks like this:

```
[
   {"id":"1","genre_id":"27","name":"aaaaa"},
   {"id":"2","genre_id":"21","name":"bbbb"}
]
```

Please, help!

Comment: post your POJO/model and interface code

Comment: go through this you got some idea https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722617/retrofit-post-using-firebase

Comment: Please share the response model you are passing in retrofit call. (Assuming you are not passing list of object)

Comment: because in response you are taking like object. Simply change it into List<YourPojoResponse>

Comment: @AMANSINGH thank you! you were right!

Comment: Hope you got your answer. You can accept it as my answer. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply change it into List

```
public class Example {
@SerializedName("id")
@Expose
private String id;
@SerializedName("genre_id")
@Expose
private String genreId;
@SerializedName("name")
@Expose
private String name;
   public String getId() {
        return id;
   }

   public void setId(String id) {
      this.id = id;
   }


   public String getGenreId() {
       return genreId;
   }


   public void setGenreId(String genreId) {
       this.genreId = genreId;
   }


   public String getName() {
      return name;
   }


    public void setName(String name) {
      this.name = name;
   }

}
```

In your call back class use like **List<`Example`>**

Hope this will helpful for others also.

Answer (score 1):

Your Object should be List of Your models something like this:

```
Model {
     String id;
     String genre_id;
     String name;
}
```

Then you should parse object with `List<Model>` . If you use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36960627/android-retrofit-design-patterns/36963162#36963162) pattern you method in `ServiceHelper` should be something like this:

```
Call<List<Model>> getListOf();
```