# Get full size of response using Retrofit or Okhttp

Tags: android, http, retrofit2, okhttp

My first time using `Retrofit2` and `okhttp3` to send `http request`. I research many sites and APIs but there a no result about "how to get fullsize of `request` and `reponse`". I'm using `HttpLoggingInterceptor` to log the `response`, but it just shows the size of `body`, not the fullsize of `response` (`headers`, `body`...). Is there a API or library to get it?

```
private OkHttpClient buildHttpClient(Interceptor interceptor) {
        ArrayList<Protocol> protocols = new ArrayList<>();
        protocols.add(Protocol.HTTP_1_1);
        OkHttpClient.Builder builder = new OkHttpClient.Builder();
        return builder.connectTimeout(mConnectTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .readTimeout(mSocketTimeoutMs, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                .protocols(protocols)
                .addInterceptor(new HttpLoggingInterceptor().setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY))
                .addInterceptor(buildCurlInterceptor())
                .build();
    }
```

Comment: have look on this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35722617/retrofit-post-using-firebase  , and also see  `Retrofit + Firebase` inside this link (detail about retrofit )

Comment: what are you trying to do? Is it for check download progress?

Comment: Post your code how you making the call right now?

Comment: @sushildlh: No, this link not related to my question.
franklinexpress: No I just want to counting the fullsize of reponse to comparing with other platform (iOS, winphone).
android_griezmann: updated.